# How to navigate to last <input> tag in fieldset using Jquery in a Drupal View form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drupal

I am not a front-end developer and I have very limited exposure to JQuery JS etc. So any help is appreciated, thanks.

Objective : - I want to put the sum of all  fields (except last ) of a fieldset into last  field of that fieldset.

The form is rather complicated, in this form, there are multiple fieldsets and each fieldset contain multiple  fields.

This form is generated by Drupal Views & I have very limited options to navigate in this form.

I can not use id, name or any other attribute as they are dynamically generated by CMS also there are hundreds of such fieldset so it is not feasible to write code for every one of them.

So, future addition of fields may alter the attributes. And I can not add my own attributes, classes, or ids to this form.

form looks something like this

```
    <fieldset>
    ------<div>
    ---------<fieldset> **this one**
    ------------------<input> 
    ------------------<input>
    ------------------<input>
    ------------------<input>
    ----------------nth <input> <= Sum of 1st to (n-1)th should come here
    -----------------------<div>
```

I think that it can be done possibly through `input:last` but can't figure out how to use it properly.

Here is the function I wrote

```
    $(function() {
                $('input').change(function() {
                    var sum = 0;
                    // Loop through all inputs 
                    $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input').each(function() {

                        sum += parseInt($(this).val());
                        console.log(sum); 
// i want to put sum into last <input> tag of the current fieldset
                    });    
                });
            }); // end function()
```

the output of console.log ($(this).closest('fieldset').find("input").last());); is

[image: NameNode console.log($(this).closest('fieldset').find("input").last());]

So, I figured that I have to extract attribute value, so far I have tried these

```
$(this).closest('fieldset').find("input").last().data('value'); Undefined
```

and

```
$(this).closest('fieldset').find("input").last().attr('value'); results in Undefined
```

Comment: Did you at least try to search for ["jquery last element"](https://api.jquery.com/last/)? Because this seems exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes , as I said, I want last <input> tag not the last element, as last element could be <label> , <div> or anything else. I did something like this $(this).closest('fieldset').("input:last") it is yeilding random input tage and $( "input" ).last() is giving last input tag of last feildset. But I guess we can modify this behaviour, which I can not figure out how

Comment: `$(this).closest('fieldset').("input").last()` is what you're looking for. Of course `$(input).last()` doesn't work, since `$(input)` is selecting *all* the `input`s in the page.

Comment: it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it should be `$(this).closest('fieldset').find("input").last()`

Comment: yeah thanks I did tried this one as well but it gave an interesting result. I am attaching the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164343/discussion-between-bhargavsushant-and-federico-klez-culloca).